# 2d array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fairly new to Vue and js and I'm trying to create a Todo App with firebase integration.
What i need it to look like is the following: there should be an option to create a new list of tasks and an option to create new tasks within this list.
So i need a list of lists.
My firebase database structure looks like this:

users (collection) -> tasks(collection) -> and inside the followin structure:

[image: screenshot]

I understand that there should be a nested v-for element right?
Something like this:

```
<div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
    <ul v-for="todo in task(?)">
    </ul>
</div>
```

But i don't understand how to approach it.
Any advice will be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```js
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
 {{task.name}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="td in task.todo" :key="td.id">
          {{ td.completed }}
   <br>
  {{ td.date }}
  <br>
  {{ td.title }}
  <br>
  {{ tdurgent }}
   

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
import {db} from './firebase';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: {}
    }
  },

  firebase: {
    tasks: {
      source: db.ref('tasks'),
      // Optional, allows you to handle any errors.
      cancelCallback(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>



firebase.js

import Firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({
  // Populate your firebase configuration data here.
  ...
});

// Export the database for components to use.
// If you want to get fancy, use mixins or provide / inject to avoid redundant imports.
export const db = firebaseApp.database();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
<div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id"> 
           <ul v-for="todo in task.keyOfArrayType" :key="todo.id" > 
                       {{todo.name}}
            </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
In the json no key id display for both outer and inner  if you interested to put key:="task.id" then you have to change the structure like
otherwise remove :key = "task.id"  and :key="td.id"

<ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
 {{name}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="td in task.todo" :key="td.id">
          {{ completed }}
   <br>
  {{ date }}
  <br>
  {{ title }}
  <br>
  {{ urgent }}
   

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!
I'm able to retrive the data when it is harcoded, but i cant figure our how to get it from firebase (using the structure in my post).
Do you happen to know how to do that?
I'm using created() hook like this:
created() {
    db.collection('users').doc('wOpmw8l8Z3UGGa7y4K7bAgs0TYJ3').collection('tasks').get().then(
      querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            'name': doc.data().name,
            'title': doc.data().title
          }
          this.tasks.push(data)
        })
      }
    )
}